# How can I export a wildcard SSL certificate from IIS to Heroku?

Tags: iis, ssl, heroku

guys!

I already have a valid and running wildcard SSL certificate from GoDaddy on an IIS server, and I need to install this certificate on Heroku (for a subdomain).

I'm still not sure if I should export the certificate from IIS (and how to import that on Heroku) or just regenerate a CSR and re-emit the certificate. If I go for the second option, will my IIS certificate keep working?

Thanks in advance!
Felipe

Answer (score 0):

Open the certificate manager from the mmc snapin and then load the local computer's certificate store.  Once insde, find your certificate and export it along with the private key.  Take the outputted file and import into Heroku.  No need to regenerate.